# Just Python Bot

Tags: python

Good evening, dear programmers, can anyone suggest a script for a telegram bot that will take all users who have registered a start in correspondence with the bot itself, be added to the list of people and, on command, collect, the bot will write a message to each user in correspondence Hello, the command can be registered by any of the users and the bot will still write hello to each user

I tried to do it, but I can’t do it, maybe someone can give advice

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")

# Список онлайн пользователей
online_users = set()

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    if user_id not in online_users:
        online_users.add(user_id)
        bot.send_message(user_id, "Вы включены в список онлайн пользователей!")
    else:
        bot.send_message(user_id, "Вы уже в списке онлайн пользователей!")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["online"])
def online(message):
    online_users_str = "\n".join([bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, user_id).user.first_name for user_id in online_users])
    if online_users_str:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Онлайн пользователи:\n{online_users_str}")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На данный момент нет онлайн пользователей.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["hello"])
def hello(message):
    sender_id = message.from_user.id

    if sender_id not in online_users:
        bot.send_message(sender_id, 'Вы не включены в список онлайн пользователей. Используйте /start.')
        return

    # Отправка уведомления о перекуре всем онлайн пользователям
    for user_id in online_users:
        if user_id != sender_id:
            user_info = bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, user_id).user
            bot.send_message(user_id, f'Привет! {message.from_user.first_name} пригласил вас.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?